# SQL - Use a Column from a Sub Select Statement as a Query in Main Select Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can you please have a look at the code and notice that I cannot use the "MYDELTOT" in the main Select Statement Query, either side of the "Union"

Code:

```
select 
    'POID' = DYN_PORDERS.ID, 'PSID' = SYS_SUPPLIERS.ID, 
    (select sum(DYN_PORDERDELS.DelQty) as MMTD 
     from DYN_PORDERDELS 
     where DYN_PORDERDELS.DelPOID = DYN_PORDERS.ID) as MYDELTOT,
    * 
from 
    DYN_PORDERSRS
inner join 
    DYN_PORDERS on DYN_PORDERS.id = DYN_PORDERSRS.RSOrderID
inner join 
    SYS_SUPPLIERS on SYS_SUPPLIERS.id = DYN_PORDERS.SupplierID
inner join 
    DYN_porderdels on DYN_PORDERS.ID = DYN_PORDERDELS.DelPOID
where 
    DYN_PORDERSRS.RSDate <= '20151031'
    and DYN_PORDERS.Qnty >= MYDELTOT

union

select 
    'POID' = DYN_PORDERS.ID, 'PSID' = SYS_SUPPLIERS.ID,
    (select sum(DYN_PORDERDELS.DelQty) as MMTD 
     from DYN_PORDERDELS 
     where DYN_PORDERDELS.DelPOID = DYN_PORDERS.ID) as MYDELTOT,
    * 
from 
    DYN_PORDERSRS
inner join 
    DYN_PORDERS on DYN_PORDERS.id = DYN_PORDERSRS.RSOrderID
inner join 
    SYS_SUPPLIERS on SYS_SUPPLIERS.id = DYN_PORDERS.SupplierID
inner join 
    DYN_porderdels on DYN_PORDERS.ID = DYN_PORDERDELS.DelPOID
where 
    DYN_PORDERSRS.rsdate  >= '20151101' 
    and DYN_PORDERS.Qnty >= MYDELTOT
```

Please help

Thanks
Mike

Comment: This is very unclear.  Please provide your error message.

Comment: the Lines with the following code come up with errors and I am unsure why
"""and DYN_PORDERS.Qnty >= MMTD"""

Errors:
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
Invalid column name 'MMTD'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 37
Invalid column name 'MMTD'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aliases are applied after the `WHERE` condition, that mean that there is nothing that is called `MYDELTOT` when the condition is applied.

One way to address it is to create the alias in a subquery, with that the alias will be associated to the value at the subquery level

```
select 'POID' = DYN_PORDERS.ID
     , 'PSID' = SYS_SUPPLIERS.ID
     , t.MYDELTOT
     , * 
from   DYN_PORDERSRS
       inner join DYN_PORDERS on DYN_PORDERS.id = DYN_PORDERSRS.RSOrderID
       inner join SYS_SUPPLIERS on SYS_SUPPLIERS.id = DYN_PORDERS.SupplierID
       inner join DYN_porderdels on DYN_PORDERS.ID = DYN_PORDERDELS.DelPOID
       CROSS APPLY (select sum(DYN_PORDERDELS.DelQty) as MYDELTOT
                    from   DYN_PORDERDELS 
                    where  DYN_PORDERDELS.DelPOID = DYN_PORDERS.ID
                   ) as t
where  DYN_PORDERSRS.rsdate <= '20151031' 
  and  DYN_PORDERS.Qnty >= t.MYDELTOT
```

Comment: not a bad statement and works as is, but

when i use a second statement and change the date to >= '20151101' 
And remove the last line, then nothing is returned

Comment: i want all past records prior to novemeber for only outstanding orders

Comment: and i want all the records for the future past the 20151101 regardless if they are completed or not

The Qnty and MyDelTot is the condition to test if the order is completted

Comment: @MikeM maybe I'm blind, but I see the same query, with only the date condition changed

Comment: So i would run the statement twice and use the union command, however is i isolate each one the past one works, but when i alter it and remove the last line it does not return any data

Comment: @seripton you are correct ignore my comment - in fact i deleted the coment re MMTD, sorry, but the statement does not run if i change the date to >= '20151101' and remove everything after the 'and'

Comment: @MikeM can you prepare some test data on sqlfiddle or somewhere else? Without the data I can't check why the query don't return data changing the date condition

Comment: i got it to work eventually, the inner joind were causing issues but this code works the best, thank you guys

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `CTE` in following:

```
 ;with cte as (
    select 'POID' = DYN_PORDERS.ID, 'PSID' = SYS_SUPPLIERS.ID, 
    (select sum(DYN_PORDERDELS.DelQty) as MMTD from DYN_PORDERDELS where                           
    DYN_PORDERDELS.DelPOID = DYN_PORDERS.ID) as MYDELTOT,
    * from DYN_PORDERSRS
    inner join DYN_PORDERS on DYN_PORDERS.id=DYN_PORDERSRS.RSOrderID
    inner join SYS_SUPPLIERS on SYS_SUPPLIERS.id=DYN_PORDERS.SupplierID
    inner join DYN_porderdels on DYN_PORDERS.ID = DYN_PORDERDELS.DelPOID
    where DYN_PORDERSRS.RSDate  <=  '20151031'
    union
    select 'POID' = DYN_PORDERS.ID, 'PSID' = SYS_SUPPLIERS.ID,
    (select sum(DYN_PORDERDELS.DelQty) as MMTD from DYN_PORDERDELS where                         
    DYN_PORDERDELS.DelPOID = DYN_PORDERS.ID) as MYDELTOT,
    * from DYN_PORDERSRS
    inner join DYN_PORDERS on DYN_PORDERS.id=DYN_PORDERSRS.RSOrderID
    inner join SYS_SUPPLIERS on SYS_SUPPLIERS.id=DYN_PORDERS.SupplierID
    inner join DYN_porderdels on DYN_PORDERS.ID = DYN_PORDERDELS.DelPOID
    where DYN_PORDERSRS.rsdate  >= '20151101' 
)
select * 
from cte
where Qnty >= MYDELTOT
```

Comment: Would this work even though Qnty isn't properly addressed?

Comment: This code did not run and came back with errors, ID was specified multiple times

Answer (score 1):

Your sql looks a bit funny but this should do it.....second one of these today

```
SELECT q.* FROM
(
  select 'POID' = DYN_PORDERS.ID, 'PSID' = SYS_SUPPLIERS.ID, DYN_PORDERS.Qnty,
  (select sum(DYN_PORDERDELS.DelQty) as MMTD from DYN_PORDERDELS where                           
  DYN_PORDERDELS.DelPOID = DYN_PORDERS.ID) as MYDELTOT,
  * from DYN_PORDERSRS
  inner join DYN_PORDERS on DYN_PORDERS.id=DYN_PORDERSRS.RSOrderID
  inner join SYS_SUPPLIERS on SYS_SUPPLIERS.id=DYN_PORDERS.SupplierID
  inner join DYN_porderdels on DYN_PORDERS.ID = DYN_PORDERDELS.DelPOID
  where DYN_PORDERSRS.RSDate  <=  '20151031'
  union
  select 'POID' = DYN_PORDERS.ID, 'PSID' = SYS_SUPPLIERS.ID, DYN_PORDERS.Qnty,
  (select sum(DYN_PORDERDELS.DelQty) as MMTD from DYN_PORDERDELS where                         
  DYN_PORDERDELS.DelPOID = DYN_PORDERS.ID) as MYDELTOT,
  * from DYN_PORDERSRS
  inner join DYN_PORDERS on DYN_PORDERS.id=DYN_PORDERSRS.RSOrderID
  inner join SYS_SUPPLIERS on SYS_SUPPLIERS.id=DYN_PORDERS.SupplierID
  inner join DYN_porderdels on DYN_PORDERS.ID = DYN_PORDERDELS.DelPOID
  where DYN_PORDERSRS.rsdate  >= '20151101' 
) q
where 
  AND q.Qnty >= q.MYDELTOT
```

Comment: Did not run
Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
The column 'ID' was specified multiple times for 'q'.

Comment: I think you need to ensure all fields in the inner query have an alias.
eg.... select 'POID' = DYN_PORDERS.ID as FieldAlias, etc ect 

And make sure that is done in both queries within q.